# Check if a user has visited a route during session

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, browser-history

I would like to detect if a user has visited a specific route during this session. I am doing this because I would only like an animation to happen once and not every time, a user returns to this page.

Ideally I would like to just save something to sessionStorage and read from it to control this functionality. I am just not sure what stores the history.

Thanks

Comment: You can just store the route path in the session storage. If it is undefined, the user will see the animation and sore the path directly in the session.

Comment: @HamzaKhattabi perfect, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome :) :)